# Return a JsonSlurper result from SoapUI

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I'm using SOAPUI to mock out a web-api service, I'm reading the contents of a static json response file, but changing the contents of a couple of the nodes based on what the user has passed through in the request.

I can't create multiple responses as surcharge is calculated from the amount passed.

The toString() method of the object that gets return by the slurper is replacing { with [ with invalidates my JsonResponse. I've included the important bits of the code below, has anyone got a way around this or is JsonSlurper not the right thing to use here?

```
def json=slurper.parseText(new File(path).text)

// set the surcharge to the two credit card nodes
// these are being set fine
json.AvailableCardTypeResponse.PaymentCards[0].Surcharge="${sur_charge}"
json.AvailableCardTypeResponse.PaymentCards[1].Surcharge="${sur_charge}"

response.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8" );
response.setContentLength(length);

Tools.readAndWrite( new ByteArrayInputStream(json.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")), length,response.getOutputStream() )
return new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockResult(mockRequest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're slurping the json into a List/Map structure, then writing this List/Map structure out.

You need to convert your lists and maps back to json.

Change the line:

```
Tools.readAndWrite( new ByteArrayInputStream(json.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")), length,response.getOutputStream() )
```

to

```
Tools.readAndWrite( new ByteArrayInputStream( new JsonBuilder( json ).toString().getBytes("UTF-8")), length,response.getOutputStream() )
```

Comment: Thank you so much, banging my head against a brick wall with this one, works a treat.